# How to retrieve the reference to an html object the fired an event in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

I am pretty new in JavaScript and I have the following problem. Into a JSP page I have something like this:

```
    <tbody>
        <c:forEach items="${listaProgetti.lista}" var="progetto" varStatus="itemProgetto">
            <tr id='<c:out value="${progetto.prgPro}" />'>
                <td><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" onchange="changeCheckbox()"></td>
                .....................................................
                .....................................................
                .....................................................
            </tr>
        </c:forEach>
    </tbody>
```

So a you can see clicking on the checkbox it is call this `changeCheckbox()` that actually is something very simple:

```
function changeCheckbox() {
    alert("INTO changeCheckbox()");
    
    var checkedRowList = new Array();
}
```

The problem is that into this function I have to retrieve what is the **input** object that fire the change event (I think something like the **this**)

How can I obtain the reference to the clicked checkbox in my previous `changeCheckbox()` function?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The element is available in the event handler content attribute, not in `changeCheckbox`. But you can pass it as an argument.

- Using `this`

  ```
  changeCheckbox(this)
  ```

  ```js
  function changeCheckbox(elem) {
    elem.style.marginLeft = '100px';
  }
  ```

  ```html
  <input type="checkbox" onchange="changeCheckbox(this)" />
  ```
- Using `event`:

  ```
  changeCheckbox(event.target)
  ```

  ```js
  function changeCheckbox(elem) {
    elem.style.marginLeft = '100px';
  }
  ```

  ```html
  <input type="checkbox" onchange="changeCheckbox(event.target)" />
  ```

Note it would be better to use `addEventListener`:

```
document.querySelector('input').addEventListener('change', changeCheckbox);
```

Then the function `changeCheckbox` will receive the event object as its first parameter, and the current target element as the `this` value.

```js
document.querySelector('input').addEventListener('change', changeCheckbox);
function changeCheckbox(e) {
  e.target.style.marginLeft = '100px';
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" />
```